# format a date in csv file as dd-mmm-yyyy format

Tags: csv

I have a basic question regarding date formatting. I have date as
 `1-Jan-00`
 which needs to be reformatted as `01-Jan-2000`. 
I tried to use the format cells as well as text function feature. But when I reopen the file as .csv file, the changes are lost. Can I kindly get help in making the changes permanent? I have to keep it as .csv file, that's my main requirement.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What program are you using?

Answer (score 0):

A CSV file is specifically a content-only formatting-free data format.  You can put `1-Jan-00` or `01-Jan-2000` or `2000-Jan-01` or whatever you want into your file.  How your program will interpret and/or display that data depends on the program.